# Submission of survey paper and graduation thesis almost in same time

Tags: publications, paper-submission, plagiarism, ieee

Location: South Korea. I am writing a survey paper and PhD graduation thesis and will submit them in 2020 July and 2020 June respectively. I am going to use Section II of my survey paper in my graduation thesis. If I submit the survey paper to the journal after I submit the graduation thesis, of course, the Section II I used will be shown as "plagiarized" in the journal`s system. In this case, will the journal accept the survey paper because the author of both works is the same or will I have to paraphrase Section II?

PS: Graduation thesis will be checked at https://www.copykiller.com/ (plagiarism detection service in Korea) and the result will be submitted to the University.

Comment: You are time travelling to submit these things?

Comment: @astronat I'd upvote your comment if I hadn't made the same mistake on the title slide for a talk I gave earlier this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ultimately up to the journal to decide - so you should contact them/consult their guidelines. I cannot imagine any scientific journal treating a thesis (PhD or MSc) as a prior publication, but this might be field dependent. In any case, you should explicitly write in your paper "This chapter is based on the author's PhD thesis to be defended (...)" or something to this effect, and I would think that this will be enough for the journal.

Comment: And since the timeline you give is a bit confusing, and since you mention what the university will do to check if the thesis is original - I'll comment that the same applies to the reverse situation: check the guidelines with your university/supervisors to confirm that (as long as it is cited correctly) it's OK for parts of the thesis to appear in journals before its submission. Again, I cannot imagine this to be a problem with a research you clearly did during your PhD (i.e it's not a 25 years old paper you scavenge for a thesis). But - ask the uni anyway.

Comment: lemon314, thank you very much for your brief answer!